# How to set a member of a bitfield created with the bitfield crate?

Tags: rust, bit-fields

I'm trying to replicate the following C bitfield and functionality in Rust:

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t directive_code : 4;
    uint8_t directive_subtype_code: 4;
    uint8_t condition_code: 4;
    uint8_t delivery_code: 2;
    uint8_t transaction_status: 2;
} Ack;

Ack ack;
ack.directive_code = 5;
ack.directive_subtype_code = 0;
ack.condition_code = 1;
ack.transaction_status = 2;
```

I've created a struct using the [bitfield](https://crates.io/crates/bitfield) crate, but I can't figure out how to set specific named members. None of the crate's examples appear to cover this

```rust
use bitfield::bitfield; // 0.13.2

bitfield! {
    pub struct Ack(u16);
    directive_code, _: 3, 0;
    directive_subtype_code, _ : 4, 7;
    condition_code, _: 8, 11;
    delivery_code, _: 12, 13;
    transaction_status, _: 14, 15;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [example given by the library](https://docs.rs/bitfield/0.13.2/bitfield/macro.bitfield.html) shows how to specify a setter method (`set_field1`):

```
bitfield!{
  pub struct BitField1(u16);
  impl Debug;
  // The fields default to u16
  field1, set_field1: 10, 0;
  pub field2, _ : 12, 3;
}
```

You need to provide a second argument for the name of the setter:

```
use bitfield::bitfield; // 0.13.2

bitfield! {
    pub struct Ack(u16);
    directive_code, set_directive_code: 3, 0;
    directive_subtype_code, _ : 4, 7;
    condition_code, _: 8, 11;
    delivery_code, _: 12, 13;
    transaction_status, _: 14, 15;
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Ack(0);
    a.set_directive_code(5);
    println!("{:016b}", a.0)
}
```

Produces the output:

```
0000000000000101
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't notice that in the docs. Thanks for your answer!